# Azure functions deployed through terraform but not showing in portal

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions

I want to deploy some Azure functions through Terraform.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "function_storage" {
  name                          = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name           = var.resource_group_name
  location                      = var.location
  account_tier                  = "Standard"
  account_replication_type      = "LRS"
  min_tls_version               = "TLS1_2"
  public_network_access_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "function_container" {
  name                  = "${var.function_name}files"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.function_storage.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "appplan" {
  name                = var.app_serviceplan_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  os_type  = "Linux"
  sku_name = "S1"
}

# Zip deployment can be very long (arroung 10 minutes)
data "archive_file" "file_function_app" {
  type       = "zip"
  source_dir = "../src/azure_functions/my_functions"
  # Use a hash of all code files as a zip filename to trigger the deployment on every changes
  output_path = "archives/${sha1(join("", [for f in fileset("../src/azure_functions/my_functions", "**") : filesha1("../src/azure_functions/my_functions/${f}")]))}-function.zip"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "funcapp" {
  name                       = var.funcapp_name
  location                   = var.location
  resource_group_name        = var.resource_group_name
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.appplan.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.function_storage.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.function_storage.primary_access_key

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      python_version = 3.11
    }
  }

  app_settings = {
    WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE       = 1
    SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true
  }

  zip_deploy_file = data.archive_file.file_function_app.output_path
}
```

When I do so, the Function App is properly deployed and my Function's files appears in the "App files" tab in the portal.

[image]

However, there is no function showing in the overview tab and I can't trigger my function.

[image]

Here are my App settings :
[image]

I don't understand this behavior. What did I do wrong and how can I fix this ?

EDIT : Adding my file structure :

```
├── infrastructure
│   ├── azure-function.tf
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── variable.tf
└── src
    ├── azure_functions
    │   └── my_function
    │       ├── commons
    │       │   ├── config
    │       │   │   ├── config.py
    │       │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │       │   ├── connectors
    │       │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │       │   │   └── sql.py
    │       │   ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── function_app.py
    │       ├── function_compute_all_profiles.py
    │       ├── function_p4_all_profiling.py
    │       ├── function_p4_profiling.py
    │       ├── host.json
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── local.settings.json
    │       └── requirements.txt
```

Comment: Add the Application setting `"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags":"EnableWorkerIndexing",` in the `Function App=>Configuration=>General Settings` and deploy again.

Comment: Please share your project's structure.

Comment: Adding `AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags` setting in my application settings didn't change anything. I edited the post with my project structure.

Comment: I think that it fails because the python requirements are not installed when using the zip_deploy_file option. My requirement.txt file is imported in the zip archive but doesn't seem to be used

Comment: Yes, that could be the reason. And can you try adding `ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD= true`.

Comment: I tried but it is still not working. I created a new Post with updated information on this issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77535771/zip-deployment-of-azure-function-do-not-trigger-the-import-of-requirements

Comment: I can see in the newly raised [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77535771/zip-deployment-of-azure-function-do-not-trigger-the-import-of-requirements) question, you have mentioned the versions along with dependencies in `requirements.txt` file.  Remove the versions and just mention the dependencies in`requirements.txt`.

Comment: Removing the dependency version doesn't work either. I tested with one single dependency, with and without version specified and it gives the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77542943/7766158), using the following app settings works :

```
app_settings = {
  SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true
}
```