# Zip deployment of Azure function do not trigger the import of requirements

Tags: python, azure, terraform, azure-functions

I want to deploy some Azure functions through Terraform.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "function_storage" {
  name                          = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name           = var.resource_group_name
  location                      = var.location
  account_tier                  = "Standard"
  account_replication_type      = "LRS"
  min_tls_version               = "TLS1_2"
  public_network_access_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "function_container" {
  name                  = "${var.function_name}files"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.function_storage.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "appplan" {
  name                = var.app_serviceplan_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  os_type  = "Linux"
  sku_name = "S1"
}

data "archive_file" "file_function_app" {
  type       = "zip"
  source_dir = "../src/azure_functions/my_functions"
  # Use a hash of all code files as a zip filename to trigger the deployment on every changes
  output_path = "archives/${sha1(join("", [for f in fileset("../src/azure_functions/my_functions", "**") : filesha1("../src/azure_functions/my_functions/${f}")]))}-function.zip"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "funcapp" {
  name                       = var.funcapp_name
  location                   = var.location
  resource_group_name        = var.resource_group_name
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.appplan.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.function_storage.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.function_storage.primary_access_key

  site_config {
    application_stack {
      python_version = 3.11
    }
  }

  app_settings = {
    WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE       = 1
    AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags       = "EnableWorkerIndexing"
    SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true
    ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD              = true
  }

  zip_deploy_file = data.archive_file.file_function_app.output_path
}
```

When I do so, the Function App is properly deployed and my Function's files appears in the "App files" tab in the portal.

[image]

However, there is no function showing in the overview tab and I can't trigger my function.

[image]

After some investigation, I found out that I can deploy a "hello-world" Azure function properly, but as soon as I add an import form an external lib, the Azure function is not recognized anymore, so I assume that there is an issue with the import of dependencies. How can I solve this issue ?

Here is an example of `function_app.py`:

```
import azure.functions as func

# Adding this import, or any other external lib will cause the problem
# If I remove this line, the function is properly recognized in Azure
import jsonschema 

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="p4_profiling", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def p4_profiling(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.HttpResponse("OK", status_code=200)
```

And here is my `requirements.txt`:

```
azure-functions==1.17.0
jsonschema==4.19.2
numpy==1.26.1
pandas==2.1.2
thefuzz==0.20.0
psycopg2-binary
```

Here is my file structure :

```
├── infrastructure
│   ├── azure-function.tf
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── variable.tf
└── src
    ├── azure_functions
    │   └── my_function
    │       ├── function_app.py
    │       ├── host.json
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── local.settings.json
    │       └── requirements.txt
```

And here is my zip file structure :

```
├── function_app.py
├── host.json
├── __init__.py
├── local.settings.json
└── requirements.txt
```

Comment: Its a known issue refer github issue here -https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/1338 and my github issue here- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/1262

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you don't need both WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE & SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT but only SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT in app_settings.

In my case, I was using WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE with python azure function & it was failing with modulenotfound error because this option is to use the deployed package 'as it is' I guess.

However, in case of python, we need an extra step i.e. installation of modules mentioned in requirements.txt file.

So, I replaced WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE =1, in app_settings in my code with SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true & it worked.

Remove WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE =1 from app_settings and try again. It should work.

Regarding the triggers not being visible on overview tab, it could be related to AzureWebJobsStorage settings which is missing in your app_settings.
The function metadata, host & trigger details are stored in storage account attached to the azure function and after deployment, azure function always tries to reach the storage account to sync the triggers.
AzureWebJobsStorage is important because it is the connection string to reach storage account.

So, you can define this setting inside app_settings as follows:-
AzureWebJobsStorage = azurerm_storage_account.function_storage.primary_connection_string.

So, your app_settings block would look like this:-

```
app_settings = {
    AzureWebJobsStorage = azurerm_storage_account.function_storage.primary_connection_string
    AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags       = "EnableWorkerIndexing"
    SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true
    ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD              = true
  }
```

Regards,
Yuvraj

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. To be more precise, it works even if I use only `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true` as app settings